# Primary admin actions block on view dissapears if change path

Tags: views, 8, routes, blocks

There is a "primary admin actions" block in the seven theme (provided by the Drupal 8 standard install profile) which only shows up if my view if the path is "admin/content"  but if I change the path to anything else, the block is gone.  where is this configured ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LocalActionsBlock is a block plugin that displays menu action links for a given route based on the [LocalActionManager::getActionsFromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!LocalActionManager.php/function/LocalActionManager%3A%3AgetActionsForRoute/8.2.x) method.

The route that corresponds to the path `/admin/content` has action links, but whichever route that corresponds to the path you are using does not have any action links defined.

[Action links](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133247) are defined in `MODULENAME.links.action.yml` file.

If the desired outcome is to have the local actions that correspond to `/admin/content` on a different path, then a module should be created that defines additional action links for those routes.

Comment: Hi Can you give me a more detailed examplel of how to  add the node.add_page to a new url?